# Windows won't install updates (Security Update for Microsoft Office 2013)

Tags: windows-8, windows-update

Today [Patch Tuesday] I installed the new Windows Updates available for Windows 8. I think there were 14 Updates altogether. All except 3 updates were installed. When i try to install the last 3 updates which are security updates for Microsoft Office 2013 64 Bit and Microsoft Office 2007 suites (I don't have Office 2007, only 2013) I get the Error: **Code 80242009 Windows Update ran into a problem.**

I have tried to install one by one the updates. The Office 2007 suites install successfully but the Office 2013 won't install. When i click on Check for Updates I again see the 2 Office 2007 suites updates, even if they were successfully installed. Can someone help with this ?

Here is a link to the update that won't install: [MS13-074 Security update for Access 2013: September 10, 2013](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2810009/en-us)

[image: Some Updates were not installed]

[image: Security Updates for Microsoft Office]

Comment: List of Windows update error codes: http://inetexplorer.mvps.org/archive/windows_update_codes.htm

Comment: Microsoft goofed up their stuff. I would wait a couple weeks till the next patch Tuesday and try again. There are a number of other [forum posts](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1_pr-windows_update/windowsupdatedt000-or-80242009/d30614d0-2928-42f2-b41c-ea208577ab5a) in the last few hours on the Microsoft forums with the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help. Request from [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2768361) the Hotfix, or download it for Office 2013 **64** bit from [here](http://hotfixv4.microsoft.com/Microsoft%20Office%202013/sp1/ace2013kb2768361fullfilex64glb/15.0.4535.1000/free/466785_intl_x64_zip.exe) or for Office 2013 **32** Bit from [here](http://hotfixv4.microsoft.com/Microsoft%20Office%202013/sp1/ace2013kb2768361fullfilex86glb/15.0.4535.1000/free/466787_intl_i386_zip.exe).

I just installed the Office 2013 hotfix package and the problem with windows update went away. Everything was installed.

> KB Article Number(s): 2768361 
> Language: All (Global)

---

The problem around this update was escalated to the proper team and new updates are being released to take care of this issue. You should try checking for updates in your computer now and try installing the updates available (don't forget to unhide the updates). This should help you resolve the issue.

[**Here**](http://blogs.technet.com/b/office_sustained_engineering/archive/2013/09/12/september-2013-public-update-update-targeting-for-microsoft-update-wsus-and-sccm.aspx) is the blog post from the Microsoft Team.

Answer (score 1):

err 80242009 = WU_E_UH_BADHANDLERXML

```
C:\Users\André>err 80242009
# for hex 0x80242009 / decimal -2145116151
  WU_E_UH_BADHANDLERXML                                          wuerror.h
# An operation could not be completed because the
# handler-specific metadata is invalid.
# as an HRESULT: Severity: FAILURE (1), FACILITY_WINDOWSUPDATE (0x24), Code 0x2009
# for hex 0x2009 / decimal 8201
  ERROR_DS_MEMBERSHIP_EVALUATED_LOCALLY                          winerror.h
# The directory service evaluated group memberships locally.
# 2 matches found for "80242009"
```

this looks like an issue an the Update server side. Phone MS support for more details. This should be free of charge.

Comment: thanks for the help. As it seems more people are experiencing the same error and can't install the update. I will wait till Microsoft resolves the issue.